# php add a value to an array when a condition is met

Tags: php

i'm still new to PHP so i need a suggestion on how am i able to add a value to an array corresponding a condition

```
 $single_items = array[]; //single item declaration
 $set_items = array[]; //set item declaration

 //fetch single items
 for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
      if($val[$i] !=0) {
           //insert $val[$i] to $single_items array
      }
 }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `[]` syntax to add a value to an array (you can also use [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)):

```
 $single_items = array(); //single item declaration
 $set_items = array(); //set item declaration

 //fetch single items
 for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
      if($val[$i] !=0) {
           //insert $val[$i] to $single_items array
           $single_items[] = $val[$i];
           // alternative
           // array_push($single_items , $val[$i]);
      }
 }
```

FYI, you had invalid syntax in your array variable declarations.

Comment: so it can also be $single_items = []; ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$single_items = array(); //single item declaration
$set_items = array(); //set item declaration

//fetch single items
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  if($val[$i] !=0) {
        $single_items[] = $val[$i];
       //insert $val[$i] to $single_items array
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  $single_items = array(); //single item declaration
 $set_items = array("Hardik", "Nirav", "Alpesh",5,"Shweta"); //set item declaration

 //fetch single items
 for($i = 0; $i < count($set_items); $i++) {
      if($set_items[$i] !=NULL) {
           //insert $val[$i] to $single_items array
           $single_items[$i] = $set_items[$i];
           echo $single_items[$i]."<br/>";
      }
 }
```